# numbers between two real numbers

Tags: number-theory

From my intuition, I believe that between two real different numbers ($a<b$), there are infinity many:

(1) rational numbers,

(2) irrational numbers,

(3) algebraic numbers and

(4) transcendental numbers.

But the question is, if I am correct, how to prove it?

I think the proof for (1) may be easy: first, find one rational number between $a$ and $b$ by comparing their integral part. If they are different, $[b]$ is the rational numbers. If they are the same, compare their first decimal place, second decimal place... until finding a "difference" (it must be found otherwise they are the same numbers). Deleting the decimal place of $a$ and $b$ after the 'difference'. Adding up divided by two yield a rational number. After finding a rational number $c_0$ between $a$ and $b$, since $b-c_0> 0$, $\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\frac1n<b-c_0$, so we can find another rational number $c_1=c_0+\frac1n$ such that $c_0<c_1<b$. In the same way we can find rational $c_2,c_3,c_4...$ which $a<c_0<c_1<c_2...<b$ .

Is this proof correct? Or there is a simpler proof, since this is an intuitive perspective. How about the proof for (2),(3) and (4)? And if there are 4 sets which each of them contains the different kinds of number between $a$ and $b$, are they countable sets?

Comment: If you want really rigorous answers, you're going to have to tell us what definitions and/or axioms you're using to give the terms "rational number" (or even just "integer") and "real number" meaning.

Comment: @dfeuer: Since I haven't study the causes about number theory formally and I just learn a little number theory, I don't really know about axioms giving the terms integer. Isn't that integer are defined from axiom of empty set?

Comment: @dfeuer: And is real number set defined from field axioms, Archimedean order axiom, and be a complete, Archimedian ordered field?

Comment: There are various different ways to define or axiomatize the real numbers. One way is to declare them to be a (Dedekind-)complete, totally ordered field (this approach is probably most common). The point is that to answer a basic question like this it's good to know what facts we're allowed to use.

Comment: So how to proof the above statement starting from that definition of real numbers?

Comment: From that one... ugh. Proving the Archimedean property is the first step there. Too much work for me tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are proofs that don't use decimal expansions. One approach is to use the fact that every real number has an integer greater than it, and thus there is an integer between $0$ and any positive real number.

Note that the density of the algebraic numbers follows immediately from the density of the rationals.

Now note that there is at least one transcendental number (the simplest proof uses the fact that the reals are uncountable and that the algebraic numbers are countable), and a transcendental number plus a rational number is transcendental.  From this, use the density of the rationals to prove the density of the transcendentals.

Now note that the density of the transcendentals immediately implies the density of the irrationals.

Note: the same sort of addition trick will also let you show that the algebraic irrationals are dense.

**Edit:** I missed something in my original reading of the question, which is resolved by the following lemma.

**Lemma:** Let $(S,\le)$ be a totally ordered set with at least two elements.

Let $T \subseteq S$.

Suppose that for any $a,b \in S$ with $a<b$, there is a $t\in T$ such that $a<t<b$.

Then for any $a,b\in S$ with $a<b$, $(a,b)\cap T$ is infinite.

*Proof:* Suppose for the sake of contradiction that it is finite.

Every finite, totally ordered set is well-ordered.

Thus … you should try to finish the proof.

To address another concern:

**Lemma 2:** Let $T$ be a nonempty set of real numbers such that for any $t\in T$ and any $q\in \Bbb Q$, $t+q\in T$.  Then every non-degenerate real interval contains an element of $T$ (and hence infinitely many elements of $T$).

Can you prove that this holds also if you use, instead of $\Bbb Q$, the set $M_b$ of rationals of the form $\frac k {b^n}$?

Comment: I know that the cardinality of rational number set and algebraic number set are the same. But how to prove cardinality of set of rational number between $a$,$b$ and set of  algebraic number between $a$,$b$ are the same?

Comment: I hope my addendum will help. Ross Millikan's answer shows how to do to do this for the reals, but I figured I'd show it in a slightly more general context.

Comment: oh, I see. But you need to make sure you can find a $T$. This lemma implies that for example, if you find a $c\in \mathbb{A}\subset\mathbb{R}$ between any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, there are infinity many '$c$'s between $a$ and $b$. But you need to make sure you can find a '$c$'

Comment: Hint: Show that there is a positive rational $q<b-a$. Then show that there is an integer $m$ such that $a<mq<b$.

Comment: but in this way $mq$ is a rational and I want to find out that $a<c<b$ while $c$ is an irrational, algebraic or transcendental

Comment: The point is that once you've figured out that the rationals are like this, you can take any single example of one of the others and slide it into place in the interval by adding a rational to it.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot really get the point. Can you each give me an example on how to slide it into place?

Comment: Let $t_0\in T$. Choose small intervals about $t$ and about $\frac{a+b}2$. Choose a rational number from each small interval and calculate their difference. When you add that to $t_0$, it will land in $(a,b)$ if you made the intervals small enough ($\frac{b-a}{\text{something or other}}$).

Comment: ok, I see, you mean adding a rational to '$t$' yield to another '$t$' inside $(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

For rationals, once you have found a rational $r$ between $a$ and $b$, there is some $n$ such that $\frac 1n \lt b-r$.  Then all $r+\frac 1m \lt b$ for $m \gt n$

For 2, take $r+\frac 1{m\sqrt 2}$.  For 3, take $r+\frac 1{m\pi}$ using the same $m$'s.

Comment: But the original number $a$ and $b$ may not be rational numbers, they can be any real numbers. Adding for example $\frac{1}{m\pi}$ may make the number become rational which is not wanted. And how to guarantee you can find a '$r$' if $a$, $b$ are not rationals.

Comment: True, but you said the proof of 1 was easy, so I assumed that.  Another way is to find a $p$ such that $\frac 1p \lt \frac 1{b-a}$ then there is a $q$ such that $a \lt \frac qp \lt b$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prove there is a positive number of the type you are looking for. By scaling by multiplication by a rational number you get another number of the same type inside any interval you want.