# In the proof for intermediate value theorem, why can we assume that there is a point between some two values in the image set of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

In [these theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem), why can we assume that there is some $u$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ for $a, b \in I$? What would happen if no such $u$ exists?

Comment: It doesn't matter that $v=f(a)$ and $w=f(b)$ are obtained by mapping some $a, b\in I$. Forget about $f$, and look like this: $v,w$ are just two real numbers, and between two real numbers there is always another real number. (E.g. if $v<w$, there is $u$ such that $v<u<w$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these theorems the function is continuous. If no such u would exist, then there's a "jump" in the function and thus it's not continuous.

Edit: As it seems I didn't "get" your question, I'd like to refer to this post and its answers, showing that there is an infinite number of real numbers between two distinct real numbers:

[Prove that there are infinitely many numbers between two real numbers. (example from Hardy's book)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117823/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-numbers-between-two-real-numbers-example)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: You mean, you think that the question was whether or not there is another real number between to distinct real numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is what I think the OP said. ("Why can we assume that there is some $u$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$...?")